# How to use ffmpeg's sws_scale from multiple threads?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I have a color space conversion function based on [sws_scale](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lsws.html#gae531c9754c9205d90ad6800015046d74). It will be called from multiple different threads during the lifetime of the application. I don't know, however, how thread-safe sws_scale is and I did not find it mentionned in its documentation.

I would assume that each thread requires its own [SwsContext](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structSwsContext.html) as this parameter will be shared, but is this enough to guarantee there won't be any internal collisions?

Answer (score 3):

You should be safe as long as each thread has it's own SwsContext value. A quick look at libswscale sources shows that it doesn't use any global variables.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg in general is not thread safe by default. However, libswsscale appears to be safe as long as each sws context is created on a separate thread.

However, when using avcodec operations, there is a callback mechanism which you can use to 
enable thread safefy for your decoding step(or other avcodec related operations):

** Note that I use this arbitrary Mutex class for illustration purposes:

```
 int ffmpeg_lock_callback(void **mutex, enum AVLockOp op)
   {
      static Mutex m;

      switch(op)
      {
          case AV_LOCK_CREATE:
          {
              *mutex = &m;
              break;
          }
          case AV_LOCK_OBTAIN:
          {
              // TODO: Lock you mutex here
              break;
          }
          case AV_LOCK_RELEASE:
          {
              // TODO: Unlock your mutex here
              break;
          }
          case AV_LOCK_DESTROY:
          {
              *mutex = 0;
              break;
          }

      }
      return 0;
  }
```

...

and this goes in your .h file:

```
extern "C"{
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
}

extern "C"
{
    int ffmpeg_lock_callback(void **mutex, enum AVLockOp op);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I must say you are right. I was under impression that this is used in creating sws_context as well; but I just checked ffmpeg's source code and that does not appear to be true. I will change my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Note: this is outdated and not neccessary anymore in newer ffmpeg versions (when compiled thread aware). ffmpeg_lock_callback is deprecated meanwhile, and does nothing.